# Can we have the tag **maths** as a synonym for *math* please

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

Being British, the tag [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) feels very ungrammatical for me so I'd like to be able to write [maths](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maths) and have it treated identically.

**Addendum.** Community sentiment seems to agree on changing [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) to [mathematics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics), for which [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) and [maths](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maths) would be aliases.

Comment: *pshaw*. (Excluding synonyms and private betas, 16 SE sites have a `math` tag, 1 has a `maths` tag.)

Comment: So what you are saying is i need to request this as a global synonym, yes?

Comment: @RoryAlsop You just made me [write up an english.SE question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171025/maths-for-mathematics-where-does-the-s-come-from). (And I think the global synonym thing is a great idea.)

Comment: We're American. As such, we expect everyone to adapt to doing everything our way, no matter how idiotic it may be. So, instead of your reasonable idea, may I suggestion you instead consider reverting to a system of weights and measures based loosely on King Henry I’s shoe size?  Okay fine, +1.

Comment: It appears as though a question needs to be tagged maths, and somebody scoring 5+ in that tag, before a synonym can be created.  But I agree, that's the way to go.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Did you end up posting this on MSE? I'd like a link if so, so I can upvote :)

Comment: @Xynariz Normally the mods (or at this point, the employees) end up handling tag synonyms.

Comment: @Wendikidd - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232361/154443

Answer (score 20):

Or better yet, make [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) and [maths](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maths) both synonyms of [mathematics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics), that way, everyone is happy and neither way of spelling is shown favoritism.

Comment: That's more or less what we did in [Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/860/9357).